# How to automatically center images?

Tags: beamer, macros, graphics, horizontal-alignment

In a beamer-LaTeX document, I want to horizontally center all images, without specifying this explicitly in each case. I did the following:

In the preamble I write:

```
\let\oig\includegraphics % original includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{{\centering\oig{#1}\par}}
```

And in the body e.g.

```
\begin{frame}{Frame title}

\includegraphics{mcg}

\end{frame}
```

The result is the error message

```
 [9

]
Runaway argument?
][
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.224 \end{frame}
```

(The snippet above generates the 10th slide of my presentation, and the last line of the snippet is line 224 of the .tex-file.)

*What am I doing wrong? How is this done correctly?*

Note: the body of the beamer-LaTeX document is automatically generated by pandoc, which means I cannot change the syntax with which images are included.

Comment: Then`\includegraphics` command takes two arguments: one required and one optional argument, so when you define it you should make sure you deal with the optional argument.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, but using `\renewcommand` I overwrite the original definition of `\includegraphics` and make my own, don't I? And my own definition has only 1 argument which is required. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are also killing the fact that `\includegraphics` is overlay-aware.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, then can you tell me how to achieve this correctly?

Comment: @A.Donda I may have commented too quickly. It looks as if my concern doesn't apply (as in: it's not the cause of the error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `beamer` class redefines `\includegraphics` to make it a robust command and overlay aware.

It's a bit complicated to get the thing right, because the redefinitions happen at begin document.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \letcs\oig{@orig\string\includegraphics}%
  \renewcommand<>\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \only#3{%
      {\centering\oig[{#1}]{#2}\par}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

Some meaningless text

\includegraphics<2>[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}

Other meaningless text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used the code from the previous version of your answer, which seems to work fine. What's the difference here?

Comment: This one works, too, though.

Answer (score 1):

And why not a simpler and safer `newcommand*` as `\newcommand*{\myincludegraphics}[2]{{\centering\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\par}}` which keep original `\includegraphics` and the options?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\myincludegraphics}[2]{{\centering\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\par}}

\begin{frame}
\myincludegraphics{width=.4\textwidth}{example-image-A}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\myincludegraphics{width=.4\textwidth}{example-image-B}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\myincludegraphics{width=.4\textwidth}{example-image-C}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I wrote in the question, "the body of the beamer-LaTeX document is automatically generated by pandoc, which means I cannot change the syntax with which images are included". Of course an alternative would be a sed script or similar, but I'd prefer a LaTeX-only version. Thanks though.

Comment: Better to use `\newcommand<>` so the new command is overlay-aware.